# Configure Django-rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I trying to setup DJango restframework in a windows machine and I get the following error when  I run the code,

Steps done.

1. Downloaded rest-framework & other utilities from github
2. Using easy_install I installed all the packages.

   Here is the confirmation msg,

   > C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install django-rest Searching for django-rest
   >   Best match: django-rest 0.0.1 Processing django_rest-0.0.1-py2.7.egg
   >   django-rest 0.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
   >
   > Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django_rest-0.0.1-py2.7.egg
   >   Processing dependencies for django-rest Finished processing
   >   dependencies for django-rest
3. Created a new project firstwebservice which created all the files.
4. Edited settings.py file and included django rest as given below,

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.sites',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       'rest_framework',
       # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
       # 'django.contrib.admin',
       # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
       # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
   )
   ```
5. Ran the project

   ```
   Error:-No module named rest_framework...
   ```

Comment: uninstall with easy, reinstall with pip. honest easy gives me so many issues.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

is rest_framework actually installed and on your PYTHONPATH?

**That looks like a basic import error.**

Suggest you:

Double check everything's installed correctly, by running "manage.py shell" and trying both "import rest_framework" and "from rest_framework import authtoken".

I would install with pip not easy if you can, easy has given me many issues like this before.

```
sudo pip install djangorestframework
```

Comment: If you're using python3, could also be because you used `pip` instead of `pip3`

Answer (score 4):

You're installing the wrong package.  The package is named `djangorestframework`, not `django-rest`.

Comment: django-rest is the folder name that I have saved the package..I thought the easy_install searches for the folder name and install whatever inside it

Answer (score 0):

another completely different cause of this "***Error:-No module named rest_framework***"

my virtual environment folder was not subfolder of my project (e.g. if you don't have an 'env' subfolder within your project, but you have your virtual env in another folder structure)

for example: I used to make all my virtual environments in a separate folder path, then I had a bat file to activate my virtual environment within each project. I had a 'master folder' for all my virtual env subfolders -- which made all of them 'findable' within the same environment PATH -- this was working for me on many prior projects, not sure if it's a python3 vs python2 issue or a DRF issue -- but -- I just upgraded from python 2.7 to 3.6 and this was my experience -- hopefully this helps someone else.

(1) navigate to your project folder (e.g. **D:\projects\myproject**)

(2) make your virtual env folder within the project folder
`virtualenv env`

(3) activate your virtualenv
`env\Scripts\activate`

**OLD FOLDER STRUCTURE: *(doesn't work)***

`D:\projects\myproject\env`         <--- python code here

`D:\python\virtualenvs\my_project`  <-- virtual env here

**NEW FOLDER STRUCTURE *(this works)***

`D:\projects\myproject`       <--- python code here

`D:\projects\myproject\env`   <-- virtual env here